# How do I change the design of XML-based menu?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am working in a project(ASP.NET WebForms) which has a Menu that is XML-based. In the ASPX-page there is only a asp.net Literal that the menu is "built" into. So I have no idea how to change the design of the Menu.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In design view "Convert into template". That did the job!

Answer (score 0):

Two options that I see, based on your info:

- Find the code that generates the HTML from the XML (an XSLT perhaps?) and tweak the output, and/or
- Inspect the generated HTML (get it from the browser) and add CSS to style it.

Maybe you can add a `<nav>` tag around that menu-literal (if it isn't already there) to help selecting it from CSS.